# Share a JPA datasource among osgi bundles

Tags: hibernate, jpa, osgi, spring-data-jpa, apache-karaf

I have this situation:

- one SQL Database instance
- two or more osgi bundles with jpa entities and spring-data repositories for "their" entities
- one of the "jpa bundles" is the "core bundle", the others depend on it (plugin bundle)

Can I use this with a singe datasource?

Example:

- "core bundle" contains `Person` entity
- "Person list plugin bundle" contains a `PersonList` entity which references to the Person entity by an `people` property

I now want to use a `PersonListService` from the "Person list plugin bundle" which uses `PersonListRepository.findByPeoplesFirstName(String firstName)`

The background is that I want that my application's database can be extended by adding an osgi bundle as a plugin.

Right now I experiment with apache karaf and hibernate 5, because of the spatial support, if that is important.

Comment: Why do you want to use "plugins" anyway? For example if you have a Person entity then all repository classes dealing with Person should be in the same bundle. I think it would not make sense to separate entities and their repositories.

Comment: I want to replace a legacy application where users can just install a "plugin" by adding a folder with php code, there is a "cache builder plugin" right now, which adds some pre computed tables to the database. This needs access to its own table and to the "core" ones.

Answer (score 0):

In OSGi it is recommended that all entities of a JPA EntityManager reside in the same bundle. You can create the EntityManager from a bundle that sees all entities but this would not work with a plugin model like you want.

Anyway creating a model on the database side that spawns several bundles might create unwanted coupling anyway. You should look into the DDD concept of bounded contexts and create your persistence contexts to implement one bounded context each.

A plugin model is not very compatible to a database anyway as the database typically needs to have a quite static structure while plugins might come and go at runtime.

You can of course share the DataSource but this is on jdbc level not on jpa level.

Comment: I was afraid of that answer, but would these idea work: each "jpa-bundle" imports the ones it needs and creates an own persistence context? I can not share objects from one to another bundle then but still use the entity and service definitions?

Comment: I don't think this would work. The reason is that the EntityManagers would have different caches but would effectively write to the same database. You can of course share some base classes but each EntityManager should write to different tables.